# How to get n-grams from a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have some doubts regarding n-grams. 
Specifically, I would like to extract 2-grams, 3-grams and 4-grams from the following column:

```
Sentences

For each topic, we will explore the words occuring in that topic and its relative weight.
We will check where our test document would be classified.
For each document we create a dictionary reporting how many
words and how many times those words appear. 
Save this to ‘bow_corpus’, then check our selected document earlier.
```

To do this, I used the following function

```
def n_grams(lines , min_length=2, max_length=4):
    lenghts=range(min_length,max_length+1)
    ngrams={length:collections.Counter() for length in lengths)
    queue= collection.deque(maxlen=max_length)
```

but it does not work since I got None as output.

Can you please tell me what is wrong in the code?

Comment: `n-grams` isn't a valid variable/function name in Python. Please check the code you posted.

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, you create empty counters and empty deques, you don't do anything with it. Your function doesn't return anything, what do you expect?

Comment: Thank you so much, @alec_djinn! Yes, it was an underscore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ngrams` dictionary has empty `Counter()` objects because you don't pass anything to count. There are also a few other problems:

- Function names can't include `-` in Python.
- `collection.deque` is invalid, I think you wanted to call `collections.deque()`

I think there are better options to fix your code than using collections library. Two of them are as follows:

You might fix your function using list comprehension:

```
def n_grams(lines, min_length=2, max_length=4):
    tokens = lines.split()
    ngrams = dict()
    for n in range(min_length, max_length + 1):
        ngrams[n] = [tokens[i:i+n] for i in range(len(tokens)-n+1)]

    return ngrams
```

Or you might use `nltk` which supports tokenization and n-grams natively.

```
from nltk import ngrams
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize


def n_grams(lines, min_length=2, max_length=4):
    tokens = word_tokenize(lines)
    ngrams = {n: ngrams(tokens, n) for n in range(min_length, max_length + 1)}
    return ngrams
```